# Error while checking syntax

Tags: verilog, xilinx, xilinx-ise

```
module mult(a, b, p);     
input [16:0] a;     
input [16:0] b;     
output p;    
wire [31:0] p;   
reg i;       
wire pv;     
wire bp; 
assign pv = 32'b0; 
assign bp = {16'b0,b} ; 
initial begin 
for (i = 0; i < 32 ; i = i + 1)     
    begin       
    if (a[i] == 1'b1)           
    begin               
       pv <= pv + bp;           
    end                 
    bp <= bp << 1 ;     
    end 
end 
assign p = pv;   
endmodule
```

I get the following error while compiling the code, 
line 37 Reference to scalar wire 'pv' is not a legal reg or variable lvalue
line 37 Illegal left hand side of nonblocking assignment
line 39 Reference to scalar wire 'bp' is not a legal reg or variable lvalue
line 39 Illegal left hand side of nonblocking assignment

Pls help.

Comment: This code demonstrates lack of understanding fundamental Verilog concepts. Before trying to fix your code, learn the differences and usages of `wire` vs `reg` vs `integer` as well as `assign` vs `initial` vs `always`, and blocking assignments (`=`) vs non-blocking assignments (`<=`)

Answer (score 0):

Left hand side of assignment in always and initial blocks must be registers. pv and bp are wires instead of registers.

you cannot put a variable in left hand side of assign and always block at the same time. Because always needs registers and assign needs wires.

I see obvious semantic mistakes in your code . You need to study basics of Verilog. You put assign which means you expect a continuous assignment but an initial block is executed just once in the beginning of simulation.
By the way output is wire by default. you can declare it as output [31:0] p;

Comment: if i assign registers to pv and bp.
I get the following error 
vERROR:HDLCompilers:246 - "mult.v" line 30 Reference to scalar reg 'pv' is not a legal net lvalue
ERROR:HDLCompilers:53 - "mult.v" line 30 Illegal left hand side of continuous assign

Hence i had put it as reg,
what should i do?

Comment: ERROR:HDLCompilers:247 - "mult.v" line 31 Reference to scalar wire 'pv' is not a legal reg or variable lvalue
ERROR:HDLCompilers:44 - "mult.v" line 31 Illegal left hand side of blocking assignment
ERROR:HDLCompilers:247 - "mult.v" line 36 Reference to scalar wire 'pv' is not a legal reg or variable lvalue
ERROR:HDLCompilers:106 - "mult.v" line 36 Illegal left hand side of nonblocking assignment
ERROR:HDLCompilers:247 - "mult.v" line 38 Reference to scalar wire 'bp' is not a legal reg or variable lvalue
ERROR:HDLCompilers:106 - "mult.v" line 38 Illegal left hand side of nonblocking assign

Comment: @Laleh , there are 3 major issues with your answer. **(1)** code will only execute at time 0 (how to do synthesizable continuous procedural blocks?). **(2)** infinite for-loop (can you figure out why?). **(3)** incorrect result (how does non-blocking work?)

Comment: I know! As I mentioned this code has many semantic errors. I just change it to be compiled!